# How can I find out which station a bookmarked song on Pandora came from?

Tags: pandora

While going through my many bookmarked songs, I sometimes wonder from which of my 30 or so radio stations a song came from.

Is there any way to know which station I was listening to when I bookmarked this song?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry.  It doesn't look like they store that information.  If they do, it's not exposed anywhere.

You can view a list of "Thumbed-up" tracks on each station's detail page, though.  In the future, you could "thumb-up" songs in addition to bookmarking them; then you'd be able to find the source station later.